# Jquery imagesLoaded Plugin Overlapping Issue

Tags: tumblr, jquery-masonry, infinite-scroll

I have a tumblelog that uses jquery masonry and infinite scrolling on the posts. The masonry only applies to the first few posts, then overlaps everything else. I know this kind of question gets asked a lot, but no one seems to know the answer. Here's my code:

```
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://static.tumblr.com/bswe8t6/UFVlryaq2/jquerymsnryv2.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
$(window).load(function(){
var $wall = $('#posts');
$wall.imagesLoaded(function(){
$wall.masonry({
columnWidth: 196,
itemSelector: '.post',
isAnimated : false
});
});

$wall.infinitescroll({
navSelector : '#navigation', 
nextSelector : 'a#nextPage', 
itemSelector : '.post', 
bufferPx : 2000,
debug : false,
errorCallback: function() { 
$('#infscr-loading').fadeOut('normal'); 
}},
function( newElements ) {
var $newElems = $( newElements );
$newElems.hide();
$newElems.imagesLoaded(function(){
$wall.masonry( 'appended', $newElems,{isAnimated: false}, function(){$newElems.fadeIn('slow');} );
});
}); $('#content').show(500);
});

</script>
```

[Here's my link.](http://s0d4pop.tumblr.com/)
Thanks!

Comment: Why OP's avatar and link doesn't exist?

Answer (score 3):

You have too many problems on your page to give you a simple answer.

1. You have 2! different "infinite scrolls" scripts being included.

   One is this line:

   ```
   <script type="text/javascript" src="http://codysherman.com/tools/infinite-scrolling/code"></script>
   ```

   And the other is included inside this other script:

   ```
   <script type="text/javascript" src="http://static.tumblr.com/bswe8t6/UFVlryaq2/jquerymsnryv2.js"></script>
   ```

   Remove the first script, and keep the second I guess.
2. The second script is the one intended to be used with the Masonry plugin, but the code example you gave is just all wrong. I don't know where to start.

   In the call to $wall.masonry,  "singleMode: true" is not a valid option.

   Several of the elements you reference in your script don't even exist on your page:

   1. '.masonryWrap' does not exist
   2. '#navigation' does not exist
   3. 'a#nextPage' does not exist
3. Your page has no navigation links anywhere, so there is nothing for the jquery infinitescroll function to use for the "navSelector" and "nextSelector"

**So to put it all together.**

The first thing you need to do is get rid of the two conflicting InfiniteScroll scripts.

Then you need to add Navigation links to your Theme Code, so you can correctly use the infinite scroll functionality (it needs to know what the link is to the next page).

**Example**: Insert this somewhere in your Theme Code, but make sure it's not trapped inside of something like {block:Posts} or {block:PermalinkPage} etc.

```
{block:Pagination}
    <div id="pagination" style="display:none;">
        {block:PreviousPage}<a id="previous_page" href="{PreviousPage}">previous</a>{/block:PreviousPage}
        {block:NextPage}<a id="next_page" href="{NextPage}">next</a>{/block:NextPage}
    </div>
{/block:Pagination}
```

After that, You need to fix your JS code to correctly reference the elements that actually exist on your page.

**Example**:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
    var $wall = $('#posts');
    $wall.imagesLoaded(function(){
        $wall.masonry({
            itemSelector: '.post',
            isAnimated : false
        });
    });

    $wall.infinitescroll({
        navSelector : '#pagination', 
        nextSelector : '#next_page', 
        itemSelector : '.post'
    },
    function( newElements ) {
        var $newElems = $( newElements );
        $newElems.hide();
        $newElems.imagesLoaded(function(){
            $newElems.fadeIn('slow');
            $wall.masonry( 'appended', $newElems, false );
        });
    });
});
</script>
```

Comment: 2 factorial different infinite scrolls! Yes, it is a mess.

Comment: You still need to insert some navigation links.

Comment: The navigation links are right before the ending div for the sidebar.

Comment: You need to put it outside of everything, including the sidebar and content, or the script is not going to see it. That's what the OP meant by "not trapped up in anything." I typically put mine right before closing body tag.